# selenium webdriver stop working when clicking an element like button or link etc

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm using IE8 and web driver. The problem I have is web driver is not performing click on any element like button,checkbox,radio button etc, but its able to verifying the elements. except clicks everything is working.
I have an application where am entering the username and password then cliking on login button but focus is still on password, if i do the double click focus is still on password with selected mode.

Am using the below code for double click

```
(new Actions(driver)).doubleClick(webelement).build().perform()
```

where `webelemet` is getting by

```
webelement = driver.findElement(By.id(xpath/id/name));
```

for single click

```
driver.findElement(By.id(xpath/id/name)).click
```

please clarify me that is it a driver problem or what else it can be 
with Firefox am not getting any issue related clicks.

Note from past two months am working on IE8 but from last week am noticing this problem, i didn't get earlier. Kindly provide any me solution

Comment: It may be some sort of webdriver problem, what version of webdriver do you use? What version of ie-driver do you use? Do you use sth like ant or maven so you can post your xml configuration of webdriver here?

Comment: yeah am using latest version(selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar) now. Actually am not using any ANT and Maven. I have designed a framework in Java language using eclipse and working on the same. Regarding Browser, my client specification is to work on only IE8 and i took latest version of it, still having the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the latest of selenium, IE driver, IE browser. Sometimes, mismatch in versions does create this kind of problem.

Comment: after updating selenium jar "selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar" and IE8,its not resolved... still facing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In IE I also faced this type of problem.

just try like this

driver.findElement(By.id()).submit();

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it's always IE?! I am using Browserstack and running the tests in various browsers  and of course in IE8 I can't click on radio button. If you are tired of everything you can always click the prblematic radio's and/or its labels using JS:

```
@driver.execute_script('return $("label[for=your_radios_id]").click() ')
```

Note, this is Ruby code so find your Java, PHP... counterparts